# Get all nested directories in a folder python

Tags: python, os.walk

This is the directory structure

```
10
  files
    2009
    2010
11
  files
    2007
    2010
    2006
```

I am trying to get full path names of all the directories inside files

```
import os
x = os.walk('.').next()[1]

print x # prints ['33', '18', '27', '39', '2', '62', '25']

for a in x:
    y = os.walk(a).next()[1]

print y # prints ['files']
```

I tried a nested for but getting stopiteration error.

What I am intending to do is get something like below,

```
['10/files/2009','10/files/2010','11/files/2007','11/files/2010','10/files/2006']
```

How to do it in python?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want only the most deeply nested directories.
If you use the `topdown=False` parameter you'll get a depth-first traversal, which will list the most deeply nested directories before their parent directories.

To filter out higher level directories, 
you could use a set to keep track of parent directories so as to omit reporting those:

```
import os

def listdirs(path):
    seen = set()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        if dirs:
            parent = root
            while parent:
                seen.add(parent)
                parent = os.path.dirname(parent)
        for d in dirs:
            d = os.path.join(root, d)
            if d not in seen:
                yield d

for d in listdirs('.'):
    print(d)
```

Comment: Why the `topdown=False`?